# How to rewrite binomial series as a geometric series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

If I want to find the taylor series for $$f(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x)}$$
I can do this by realising this is the sum of a geometric series:
$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} x^{n}$.

But it's also possible to interpret it as a binomial series:
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x)}=(1+x)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\begin{array}{c}-1 \\ n\end{array}\right) x^{n}$$ where $\left(\begin{array}{l}k \\ n\end{array}\right)=\frac{k(k-1)(k-2) \cdots(k-n+1)}{n !}$.

How does one, in general, go from a binomial series (when k=1) to a geometric series?

Comment: $\binom {-1}n = (-1)^n$.

Comment: @player3236 Haha I thought that would be true. But I can't see why or how to get that?

How does the binomial coefficient even make sense for negative values?

Comment: Using your definition, $\binom {-1}n = (-1)(-2)(-3)\dots(-n)/n!$. The definition indeed extends to negative values (and real values of $k$)

Comment: $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma (k+1) \Gamma (n-k+1)}$
but $\Gamma(0)$ is undefined